# How to update value of element in an array stored as a FieldValue in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I stored an Array as a FieldValue in one of my document in Firestore. Now I want to update one of its element value. As per the documentation I can use arrayRemove or arrayUnion function to remove the element from array but I didn't see any method to update the value of element. Is there any way that I can help me to update the elements' value.

[image]

Here I stored array in "patients" field of document. This array represents list of patients. Look at 0th position of element. Here status's value is "current". I want to update this to "processed". Is there anyway that I can do so.

Also is there any way that I can query the elements of array on the basis of the value placed on status key.

Comment: To add to the excellent and accepted answer. Array's can be challenging to use (as can be seen by the answer). It would be probably better to let Firestore generate your documentID's with .addDocument (swift). They are unique, highly queryable and alleviates the obstacles that arrays present in NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per the documentation I can use arrayRemove or arrayUnion function to remove the element from an array.

There is no way you can use one of those functions to add or remove elements from an array that contains objects. To be able to use those functions, your array should contain for example literal strings. In that way, you can add or remove one of the elements using `arrayRemove()` or `arrayUnion()` functions.

> I didn't see any method to update the value of an element.

There is no update method. `arrayUnion()` method will add a new element in the array only if it does **not** exist. If you want to update an element, you have to remove it first from the array and then add the new one. This is also available in the case of strings and **not** in the case of objects.

> Is there any way that I can help me to update the elements' value.

Yes, two ways in which you can achieve this. The first one would be to get the entire document, get the `patients` property as a list of hashmaps, iterate through its elements, make the desired changes and write the document back. The second one would be to transform that array into a subcollection where each patient will become a document. In this way, you can simply update add or remove a document using the corresponding functions.

> Also is there any way that I can query the elements of the array on the basis of the value placed on the status key.

Using your current document structure, no. If you want to query the patients of a user based on the value of a specific property, you should definitely use the second approach. There is no way you can achieve this using your actual schema.